# PowerShell enum value that represents all

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

Given my current `enum`:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
   [System.Flags] 
   public enum FlagsEnum {
      None = 0,
      SummaryInfo = 1,
      ReportOptions = 2,
      ParameterFields = 4
   }
"@
```

Is there a way to create an entry that sets all bits to 1?  This syntax causes errors:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
   [System.Flags] 
   public enum FlagsEnum {
      None = 0,
      SummaryInfo = 1,
      ReportOptions = 2,
      ParameterFields = 4,
      All = (SummaryInfo -bor ReportOptions -bor ParameterFields)
   }
"@
```

** edit **

Changed the declaration:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
   [System.Flags] 
   public enum FlagsEnum {
      None = 0,
      SummaryInfo = 1,
      ReportOptions = 2,
      ParameterFields = 4,
      All = (SummaryInfo | ReportOptions | ParameterFields)
   }
"@
```

The code:

```
$flags = [FlagsEnum]::All

if ( $flags -band [FlagsEnum]::SummaryInfo ) { write-host "add SummaryInfo" } 
if ( $flags -band [FlagsEnum]::ReportOptions ) { write-host "add ReportOptions" } 
if ( $flags -band [FlagsEnum]::ParameterFields ) { write-host "add ParameterFields" }
```

results:

```
Add-Type : Cannot add type. The type name 'FlagsEnum' already exists.
At C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\enums.ps1:3 char:9
+ Add-Type <<<<  -TypeDefinition @"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (FlagsEnum:String) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TYPE_ALREADY_EXISTS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: `InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
  [System.Flags] 
  public enum FlagsEnum {
    None = 0,
    SummaryInfo = 1,
    ReportOptions = 2,
    ParameterFields = 4,
    All = (SummaryInfo | ReportOptions | ParameterFields)
  }
"@
```

Remember that inside that here doc, you're not really writing PowerShell, you're writing C#.

*Edit for posterity based on comments from the asker of the original question*

The actual error that was being shown stated that the type already existed. This is because an earlier version of the code had been run in the same PowerShell session. An unfortunate limitation of PowerShell is that you can't add a type, tweak it and then re-add it (which makes developing scripts that define their own types painful).

Comment: The syntax that you suggest does work, but I'm getting a `The type name 'FlagsEnum' already exists` error.  Thoughts?

Comment: The reason you are getting the "already exists error" is because the type already exists in your PowerShell session. Try running it in a new window

Comment: I've added a note about the type already existing, to make it clearer to anyone else reading this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're defining a C# enum so use C# operators e.g.:

```
 All = SummaryInfo | ReportOptions | ParameterFields
```